# Java template inheritance with wildcard

Tags: java, inheritance, covariance

In Java the following code won't compile:

```
class Pair <T1> { }

class Real {
    Pair<Real> sqrt() { 
        return null;
    }
}
class Complex extends Real { 
    Pair<Complex> sqrt()  {  
        return null;
    }
}
```

Makes sense, because `Pair<Complex>` doesn't inherit from `Pair<Real>`.

However, I was surprised to find out that this code will compile:

```
class Pair <T1> { }

class Real {
    Pair<? extends Real> sqrt() {
        return null;
    }
}

class Complex extends Real {
    Pair<? extends Complex> sqrt()  {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This seems to imply that `Pair<? extends Complex>` does in fact inherit from `Pair<? extends Real>`

Can someone explain this? What exactly is happening here?

Comment: Well, `Pair<Real>` states that the pair will contain any real numbers while `Pair<Complex>` only allows for complex numbers which is more restrictive. But `Pair<? extends Real>` states that the pair can contain real numbers or any subclasses and thus the more specific `Pair<? extends Complex>` matches that. Since the user can't add or replace any numbers in the pair the both wildcard definitions are covariant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to think about it is this:

You're required in `Complex` to provide a method that returns something of type `Pair<T>` where `T` can be anything that inherits from `Real`. Your `Complex` implementation changes the return type requirements to `Pair<U>` where `U` can be anything that inherits from `Complex`.

However as `Complex` inherits from `Real`, anything extending `Complex` will also extend `Real`, so you are still providing a method that guarantees a return type of `Pair<T>`.

---

To formalise it a bit:

```
Pair<? extends Complex> ≡ Pair<? extends Complex extends Real> ≡ Pair<? extends Real>
```

---

The difference in your first example that doesn't compile is that your `Complex` implementation is actually restricting the return type, as not every `Pair<Real>` is a `Pair<Complex>`.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO Angelika Langer provides the best [explanation (see also subsequent answers)](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ203), yet hard and exhaustive, for your problem.

Also, when in doubt if two types are actually subtype and supertype, following helper method proved useful to me. The method is not intended to run. Just type generic argument explicitly and see if it compiles.

```java
public <T,U extends T> void m() {}

this.<Set<Object>,Set<Integer>>m(); -- wont compile
this.<Set<? extends Object>,Set<? extends Integer>>m(); -- compiles
```